# Why is `__del__` method not called if an instance is stored?

Tags: python, overriding, decorator, del

To deepen my understanding of decorators I tried to come up with an alternative solution for the `count_instances` decorator in Tonie Victor's [blog](https://soshace.com/understanding-python-decorators-and-how-to-use-them-effectively#crayon-64779763ad5a5605076850) (section *Common Use Cases of Class Decorators*).

Instead of using a function, I use a class as a decorator and I extend the functionality to keep a proper count even when instances of the decorated class are deleted.  For that I decorate the `__del__` method of the decorated class.

In fact this works as expected on my simple test cases. However, when I try to change the decorator from an instance *counter* to an instance *tracker* that contains a list of all instances, it all of a sudden does not work as expected anymore.

More specifically, if I add the instance of the decorated class to a list in the `InstanceCounter` class, the (decorated) `__del__` method isn't called anymore if I delete an instance and the counts are wrong.

Note that I have not implemented all functionality for the tracker yet. I planned to

1. replace the `_count` attribute with a property that returns the length of `_instances`;
2. add a `self._instances.pop(self._instances.index(obj))` to `wrapper`.

```py
class InstanceCounter:
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._instances = []
        self._count = 0
        if hasattr(cls, "__del__"):
            del_meth = cls.__del__
        else:
            del_meth = None
        cls.__del__ = self._del_decorator(del_meth)
        self._wrapped_cls = cls

    @property
    def instance_count(self):
        return self._count

    def __call__(self):
        self._count += 1
        obj = self._wrapped_cls()
        # self._instances.append(obj)        # When this line is uncommented...
        return obj

    def _del_decorator(self, del_method):
        def wrapper(obj):
            self._count -= 1
            if del_method:
                del_method(obj)

        return wrapper


@InstanceCounter
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __del__(self):                  # ... this method will not be executed.
        print(f"Deleting object of class {__class__}")


@InstanceCounter
class OtherClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

# Test cases with expected output. 
my_a = MyClass()
print(f"{MyClass.instance_count=}")  # MyClass.instance_count=1

my_b = MyClass()
print(f"{MyClass.instance_count=}")  # MyClass.instance_count=2

del my_a
print(f"{MyClass.instance_count=}")  # MyClass.instance_count=1

oth_c = OtherClass()
print(f"{OtherClass.instance_count=}")  # OtherClass.instance_count=1

oth_d = OtherClass()
print(f"{OtherClass.instance_count=}")  # OtherClass.instance_count=2

del oth_c
print(f"{OtherClass.instance_count=}")  # OtherClass.instance_count=1

del oth_d
print(f"{OtherClass.instance_count=}")  # OtherClass.instance_count=0
```

Why is the `__del__` method not called if an instance of the class is saved in the decorating class? How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you think that the `__del__()` method *should* be called?

Comment: *"Why is the __del__ method not called if an instance of the class is saved in the decorating class?"* The reference count of the instance is (at least) 1, because of the reference to that instance in the decorating object's "self._instances". You may want to use weakrefs? https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html

Comment: @slothrop Wouldn't the reference count decrease by 1 if I add the line with `pop` (step 2)? I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: You might want to check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFjuQmlwXgU) by mCoding.

Comment: I don't think that would work, because there is a chicken-and-egg problem: the reference count will not fall to 0 without that 'pop', so nothing triggers the call to the del_decorator's wrapper that would invoke the 'pop'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After uncommenting `self._instances.append(obj)`, `my_a = MyClass()` creates two references to the object - `my_a` and `MyClass._instances[0]`. `del my_a` deletes only the first reference, so the object is not destroyed and, thus, `__del__` method is not called.

If this is not what you want, you can store a list of weak references instead of normal references. To do this, just replace
`self._instances.append(obj)` with
`self._instances.append(weakref.ref(obj))`.